# Service Fabric Update Manifests: Pipeline Artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-build-task

Currently, the **Update Service Fabric manifests** task within Azure DevOps Pipelines doesn't support the newer **Pipeline Artifact** type and I assume it's looking for the older **Build Artifact** instead.

I've checked GitHub, but there doesn't seem to be any indication that this is to be supported (certainly anytime soon). Does anybody know if this is definitely the case?

And also, has anybody come up with a workaround for this? I know there's an option to **Override Existing Package Artifact** on the task so this could potentially be set to false in order to prevent the task from erroring and then use a mechanism of retrieving the artifact and copying over to the assumed package location manually. All possible with a bit of PowerShell I'm sure.

[image: Update Service Fabric manifests task]

**UPDATE**

Warning message received during build...

[image: Build task warning]

Comment: Could you share the error message from this task? For my knowledge, the pipeline artifact and build artifact are same. They are just the built result from the build pipeline. Can you try entering your "artifact alias name" instead "drop" in "Package Artifact Name"?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I've updated the question to show the message we are seeing. I will have a look at the 'artifact alias name', but this matches the name provided in the Publish Pipeline Artifacts as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi @smd any luck with the `artifact alias name`? is Update Service Fabric manifests task in the build pipeline or release pipeline?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT, updating the `artifact alias name` didn't help unfortunately. It's performing the task as part of the build pipeline. I may have to look through the task scripts on GitHub to see where the issue lies.

Comment: Hi @smd Could you please have a try using **Publish build artifact task** to publish your artifact. I have read a [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/790426/unsupported-artifact-type-pipelineartifact.html) said download build artifact cannot download the artifact published by publish pipeline artifact task. Maybe Update Service Fabric manifests task use down build artifact internally and it caused the problem.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT, we used to use Publish Build Artifacts but it added ~10-15 mins onto the build time in comparison to using the Publish Pipeline Artifacts task so would be reluctant to revert back to that if I'm honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After raising this as an issue on GitHub, it has been communicated that the artifact type **Pipeline Artifact** is not currently supported by the **Update Service Fabric manifests** build task (as of version 2).

It has been added to the backlog as an enhancement.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12322